# What makes you think you could generate random 64Bit values in C++11?

Tags: c++11, random, 64-bit

Maybe I got the whole idea wrong but in my attempt to create a RNG using what is provided in the random-header I found out that there is a lack of uniformness in the least significant bits of the random numbers. In fact most of the times when I look at the numbers in hexadecimal display in the Visual Studio 2010 debugger they end in 0x00.

So I wrote this little bit of code to confirm my suspicion:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937_64 generator(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned long long> distribution(0, ULLONG_MAX);

int cnt[256];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    cnt[i] = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    cnt[distribution(generator) & 0xFF]++;
```

it turnes out that about 95% of the random numbers generated end with "0x00".

Did I get the idea of uniformness wrong?
What do I have to do in order generate uniformly distributed 64 bit unsigned integers?

I intended to use them as basis for lower-resolution random numbers I could derive by masking them with the corresponding 0xF....F pattern.

Performance is not an issue. Flexibility is.

Comment: No repro.  Update your VS version.

Comment: You're right. This only occurs when using "Visual Studio 2010 (v100)" platform toolset. Everything is ok when setting the project properties to "Visual Studio 2012 (v110)". I just edited my post.

Comment: "I intended to use them as basis for lower-resolution random numbers" - you're reinventing `std::uniform_int_distribution`. Even if your VS2010 toolset is buggy, the better solution would probably be Boost.Random.